# Google Analytics event flow

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to use Google Analytics to examine how users progress through my site. The problem is that my site operates entirely upon AJAX.

I have set up "events" using:
`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', category, action])`

These are being recorded by Analytics, but I am unable to view how users progress through each event.

In other words, currently I can see that 10 users added a post and that 7 users added a comment to a post.

What I want to see is how many of the users who added a post then also added a comment.

Does Analytics allow you to view/track this kind of user flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of or in addition to, you could use virtual page views which you could then put as steps in a goal funnel. Virtual page views will also be added to the overall stats with all the associated information provided there.

`_gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/post/comment');`

If necessary, you can filter these page views out of any profile the you want stats that are not inflated by the virtual page views. If you haven't already, create a "raw" or unfiltered profile that is a bucket for all the stats and any other profile you may need based on filters.

Also, take a look at the Event Flow report under events. You may find what you are looking for there already.

Comment: I think the Event Flow page is actually what I needed, but I may try out '_trackPageView' to see if it works better. Analytics feels very un-intuitive to me. It seems odd that you have to go into admin, then goals to add events. Then the "Goals" page is under "Conversions" and the "Events" page is under "Content"...